# Subversion seems unforgiving if making changes to directories in Repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Still getting a feel for Subversion and TortoiseSVN.

One thing I've noticed is that if there needs to be a change to how directories are structured or if they need to be renamed or deleted, and then trying to do update/commit seems to cause issues.  Cleanup from TortoiseSVN most of the time doesn't seem to resolve this.  Most of the time, I will put the directory back in place so updates/commits can be completed successfully.

I realize setting up a Repository on the SVN Server needs to be carefully planned out however there are always changes or something unforeseen.

Any recommendation or advice on a best method for resolving or avoiding these issues?

Comment: You need to describe these "issues" and how you're performing the moves, renames & deletions. Most likely, you're doing them without issuing the proper Subversion commands, which will screw up your WC.

Comment: I'm not working from the Subversion Server, I'm only working with the TortoiseSVN Client, so I'm not wokring from the command line.  An example would be that I rename a directory from the Repository and from the WC, if run update/commit, I've gotten errors where it is still looking for the original directory.  If I add it back into the Repository, it at least gives me a work-around.

Comment: What do you mean "rename a directory from the Repository"? Do you mean that you renamed it using the Repository Browser? What then do you mean by "errors where it is still looking for the original directory"? Are you talking about "tree conflict"s or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're changing files in the repository? That should all be done automatically by svn when you run commit from tortoise, just change the working copy as you need and then commit. If you could give some step by step details of what you're doing (including the commands used and whether they're being run in tortoise or in the operating system's file browser etc) you'll get more detailed replies.